# Get Started with Oracle Express Edition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm novice in oracle.I'm using oracle express 10.2.0 but i don't know how to create my own database and where my database is created.(The path of my new database).

Answer (score 3):

Not to be confused : in Oracle terminology, a database instance (called XE) is automatically created during installation (limitation : there can be only one database instance running at a time in Oracle Express).

What other vendors usually call a database (like in Sql Server) is a [Schema](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#CNCPT111) in Oracle. To create one, use the [`CREATE USER`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm#i2065278) command (and not the [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm#SQLRF01313) command : welcome to the marvelous world of Oracle !), using SQL*Plus or APEX.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that the limitation is actually that you can only run one instance at a time. See http://devtime.blogspot.com/2006/01/creating-oracle-xe-database-manually.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to create a <strike>database</strike> schema through the web administration interface. Check the [Getting Started Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25610/toc.htm) from the [Oracle Database 10g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html).

For the path to the files, this article may help: [Creating an Oracle (XE) database manually on XP](http://devtime.blogspot.com/2006/01/creating-oracle-xe-database-manually.html).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new database is easiest with the web frontend. Look inside the start menu for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 10g XE comes with the integrated browser interface. You can access it from `http://machine-name:port/xe`

It is almost similar to Oracle Enterprise manager. You can also try using [Oracle Application Express](http://apex.oracle.com) on it, and develop web applications.